# Protector for camera lens window on HTC Desire Z? (protect from scratches)

Tags: camera, screen-protector

Given that this phone provides no protection against scratches on the window for the camera lens, unlike for example, the Nokia N82 (great cameraphone which I also own), are there any adhesive transparent protectors that can be placed over this window but which would not affect image quality?

I've bought the screen and body protector from zagg.com by recommendation and am pleased with that but this offers no protector for the camera itself. (see: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2935/best-screen-protector-htc-desire-z )

I would think that protecting the camera lens window on this phone (and many others) would be more of a priority as this is actually functionality of the phone that needs to be protected - i.e. clear photos and video, rather than cosmetic - which most screen protectors do a good job of but fall short on the camera protection, it seems.

Comment: Surprised no-one is interested in protecting their mobile phone cameras. Really surprised. Anyone?...

Comment: @Rob: given that most people does not use their phone camera to take high quality images, I'm not that surprised.

Comment: I replace my phone every year, surely it will last me that long?

Comment: @Ivo Flipse you're fortunate. Do you buy sim-free or does your operator contract offer you good deals in this?

Comment: They discount me for about half the price of the phone, so I still pay a considerable amount, but in exchange I get to have new phones each year :-)

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Disgree: This 'phone is many megapixels and takes 720p video. Sure, it's not an SLR but it is capable of taking good pictures, not pixelated dull pictures when phone cameras first came out. Nokia managed a protector with the  N82 and N95, why couldn't HTC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can understand your concern, but I've also never seen a film that specifically covers the camera lens window. I haven't used a Zagg, but other screen films I've purchased in the past included the excess film on the card - if the Zagg included this you could possibly cut your own square or circle to cover the lens window. Otherwise I'd suggest checking your retailer of choice for another inexpensive film that you can use to cut your own window from.

In the past I've purchased screen protectors on clearance from places like Staples, Walmart, etc for obsolete devices so I could cut them to protect camera screens, etc.

Comment: +1 and accepted: Cutting out a trimmed cornered rectangle from excess film is exactly what I did, in the end. It took me a few tries to get it just about right to fit though :) The final version was OK and by then I was tired of trying so am happy with that. Video and film looks OK through it though I'm reluctant to peel it off to compare without this protector, as the cutout I made may reduce its adhesiveness effectiveness doing so when I re-apply it to the lens window. :)